# flask occurs no navbar button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I use the bootstrap template in my Flask project there is no button on my website when I debug it. 
And jquery version is 3.3.1 min , bootstrap version is 4 min 
Fig1 is my html, and Fig2 is expected. My navigation button does not appear
[my html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2MYm.png)[expected html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKarZ.png)  [elements review by chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXyx4.png)

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">切换导航</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       </button>
       <a class="navbar-brand navbar-title" href="/">ATM Tech</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="/">艾特码科技</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">彭锟的技术博客</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Which bootstrap template are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the size of your browser window, or inspect in responsive mode. Also, go to bootstrap docs and see if you have all the right class names, collapsed doesn't seem like a valid one.

Comment: oh my my , you're right , I just find it responsive mode only run in mobile device. thx